# Limit of probabilities under equivalent measure

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

I have a question. Let $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ be equivalent measures, and let $A_n,n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of events on the regarding measure space. Does it hold true, that
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)=0 \Rightarrow \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{Q}(A_n)=0. 
\end{align}

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, $P << Q$ implies $P(A) \to 0$ as $Q (A) \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any proof or reference for this? I am not sure how to do it

Comment: Theorem 6.11 in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!